# Does it Matter if Categorical Features are Standardized?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, standardization

I have a dataset I am scaling in order to run a machine learning algorithm. I know it's bad practice to standardize binary features in regression, but I was wondering if it actually makes a difference in classification problems whether if categorical variables are standardized or not.

Comment: Standardizing binary / categorical features makes no sense, as they will be internally transformed into numeric, in doing so you are making some assumptions about the data which are likey not to be true.

Comment: You’re absolutely right, but I was thinking that if e.g. you have a cat feature with values 1,2,3 even if you standardize  it you will end up with three distinct values for each instance so as long as they are different from each other it shouldn’t matter right ?

Comment: It does matter, it's true that they will have different values and retain the numeric ratio (the data will only be scaled by some constant), but they will be treated differently by your model, you will add some order to them which does not exist. If, however, you scale them and them refactorize them you will basically do nothing, so there is no point.